# styled-components - how to set styles on html or body tag?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, jss

Ordinarily, when using pure CSS, I have a style sheet that contains:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

When using `styled-components` in my React project, how do I set styles for the `html` or `body` tags? Do I maintain a separate CSS file just for this purpose?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can, of course, maintain a separate CSS file that you include in your HTML via a `<link>` tag.

#### For `v4`:

Use [createGlobalStyle](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) from Styled-components.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
  }
`

<React.Fragment>
  <GlobalStyle whiteColor />
  <Navigation /> {/* example of other top-level stuff */}
</React.Fragment>
```

#### Pre `v4`:

Styled-components also exports an `injectGlobal` helper to inject global CSS from JavaScript:

```
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
`
```

See the [API documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api) for more information!

Comment: Looking at this you can only hard code the HTML and BODY elements. If you wanted to allow for varying background colors on the BODY element how would you be able to dynamically set them?

Comment: One should add that the correct way of using global styles is not wrapping your components in it but rather calling it as an independent component.

Answer (score 25):

**As of Oct, 2018.**

> **NOTE**
>
> The injectGlobal API was removed and replaced by createGlobalStyle in
>   styled-components v4.

According to docs `createGlobalStyle` is

> A helper function to generate a special StyledComponent that handles global styles. Normally, styled components are automatically scoped to a local CSS class and therefore isolated from other components. In the case of createGlobalStyle, this limitation is removed and things like CSS resets or base stylesheets can be applied.

**Example**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
  }
`

// later in your app

<React.Fragment>
  <Navigation /> {/* example of other top-level stuff */}
  <GlobalStyle whiteColor />
</React.Fragment>
```

Read more on [official docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle).